# Setting border for checkable QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget

I have added some check-able QListWidgetItem and I have challenge setting the border color for the checkboxes. setForeground function only sets the color of the checkbox text.
Any suggestion please.

This is my sample code creating the check-able QListWidgetItems:

```
    watch_list = ["Protesters", "Local news staff", "Techfluencers"]
    for category in watch_list:
        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(category)
        self.checkBox.setFlags(self.checkBox.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
        self.checkBox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
        self.checkBox.setForeground(QtGui.QColor('#FFFFFF'))
        self.watchListslistWidget.addItem(self.checkBox)
```

I have tried

```
     self.watchListslistWidget.setStyleSheet("""
                                            QListWidget::item {              
                                                 border:1px #FFFFFF
                                            }
                                        """)
```

But it sets the all background of the QListWidget to white.

Comment: your question is confusing since when you indicate the color of the border of the checkbox, what do you mean? The border of the item or the checkbox square?

Comment: The border of the checkbox square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using indicator as follows:

```
self.watchListslistWidget.setStyleSheet("""
                                       QListWidget::indicator{
                                            border: 1px solid white;
                                       }
                                       """)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a delegate:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class CheckBoxDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super().initStyleOption(option, index)
        option.palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Button, QtGui.QColor("red"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.watchListslistWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.watchListslistWidget)

        watch_list = ["Protesters", "Local news staff", "Techfluencers"]
        for category in watch_list:
            checkBox = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(category)
            checkBox.setFlags(checkBox.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
            checkBox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
            self.watchListslistWidget.addItem(checkBox)

        delegate = CheckBoxDelegate(self.watchListslistWidget)
        self.watchListslistWidget.setItemDelegate(delegate)


def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I have tested your code but can't see any color set on the border of the checkbox square

Comment: @B.Obilo try add `app.setStyle("fusion")`